# Exclude names like "backup" from cpbackup-exclude.conf in cpanel backup

Tags: backup, cpanel

I want to exclude any file that has the word backup in it and is in format of zip , tar.gz  from cpanel backup  I do not know exactly what I should enter in cpbackup-exclude.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can add "cpbackup-exclude.conf" in a global or user level.

Global:
*/etc/cpbackup-exclude.conf*

User level:
*/home/username/cpbackup-exclude.conf*

The entries would be like this:

```
*/backup-*tar.gz
*/backup-*zip
*/backup*gz
*/cpmove*
```

Answer (score 0):

I contacted cpanel and they told me the following works. Has been tested

```
/*backup*.sql
/*backup*.tar
/*backup*.tar.bz2
/*backup*.tar.gz
/*backup*.zip
```

So the above will make sure any sql , tart etc that has the word backup in it inside all folders are excluded from backup